# In Terraform, how do I get distinct tuples in a list by an attribute?

Tags: terraform

In other words, is there a way to specify the identity of a tuple to some function in order to make a set of them?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
locals {
  tuples = [
    {a=1, b=2},
    {a=1, b=3},
    {a=5, b=4},
  ]
  a_map = {for t in tuples: t.a => t...}
  distinct_tuples = [for k, v in a_map: v[0]]
}
```